# Leaving Site alert is showing leave any page Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I made a site in WordPress, when I leave some of the pages of my site it shows a "Leave Site" alert. I want to remove it from my site. How do I remove this from our site?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e484N.png)

Please help me if anyone knows the solution.

But I also need to show another popup while leaving some pages. How can that will work?

Comment: As you haven't shared any code so far, it's close to impossible to provide help. Why not search that alert message in your code base?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is created by some JavaScript code in your codebase that is most likely listening to the `beforeunload` event.

You will have to find the code in your codebase that creates the alert and remove it.

You could also try stopping the `beforeunload` events propagation by inserting your own JS at the top of the header (or before whatever JS causes the alert is loaded):

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

But be warned that this might break features on your site that rely on the `beforeunload` event.

Comment: But I also need to show another popup while leaving some pages. How can that will work?

Comment: @NehaRajput Then you will have to find the code that generates the specific message you want to remove and remove it. When it comes to finding it, personally I would try a grep-based approach, perhaps look for `beforeunload` event calls or the text shown in the alert.

Comment: I searched it in all over the site but not able to find it